# How to get Post collection in magento by fishpig wordpress extension 4.0?

Tags: wordpress, magento-1.9, fishpig

I want to get posts collection in magento by fishpig wordpress extension  4.0.
In previous version it gives collection by

```
$mypostcollections = Mage::helper('wordpress/post_collection')
                 ->addIsPublishedFilter()
                 ->addCustomFieldFilter("is_featured_post", "1")
                 ->load();
```

But after update extension to version 4.0 it is not working. Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of changes in the version 4.0 upgrade but the code you posted has never worked (you can't create a collection via a helper in that way). The code below will work in version 4.0.

```
<?php
 // Load a collection
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection');

// Filter by post type 'post'. Not required for version 3.*
$collection->addPostTypeFilter('post');

// Change to addIsPublishedFilter if using version 3.*
$collection->addIsViewableFilter();

// Apply a meta value (custom field) filter
$collection->addMetaFieldToFilter('is_featured_post', 1);

// Load the collection
$collection->load();
```

Comment: can u please tell what is 'is_featured_post'?  name of the custom field/value or where do i get it from my custom field? @Ben

Comment: This is the custom field name.